# How to implement comments on specific fields in wordpress?

Tags: comments, content

I have a custom content type in Wordpress, having some custom fields. I need some of this fields to be opened to comments, that is

```
Content Flower
--> Field Name
--> Field Color
--> Field Flavor
--> Field Needs sun
--> Field Description
```

Registered user must be allow to add a comment about Color, for example, to tell their opinion

```
Content Name    = 'Marguerite'
Color           = 'Yellow'
Color Comment 1 = 'In my country, Marguerite are Purple'
Color Comment 2 = 'Black!'
Color Comment 3 = 'Where do you live, guys?!?'
```

There's a way to achieve this in Wordpress, that is not coding the whole behavior by myself? I'm not adding details, for the problem can be dealt with in several ways.

Comment: Just an idea. You can have post types for all of fields. For example. `flower` post type is hierarchical, and you add `name`, `color` etc as different child post type.

Comment: Wow, this is interesting. I'll give surely a try!